# Magento 2: Change quote currency code before place order with Observer

Tags: magento2, sales-order, quote, currency

I am trying to change the quote currency before placing any order.

I have used below event for that.

> Vendor\Module\etc\frontend\events.xml

```
<event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
    <observer name="change_currency_before_place_order" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\BeforePlaceOrder" />
</event>
```

> Vendor\Module\Observer\BeforePlaceOrder.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class BeforePlaceOrder implements ObserverInterface
{    

 protected $_checkoutSession;
 private $logger;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session
 */
 protected $catalogSession;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
)
{   
    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    $this->catalogSession = $catalogSession;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{   
   $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote(); 
   $this->logger->info('inside place order observer');
   //$this->storeManager->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode('EUR'); 
   $quote->setQuoteCurrencyCode("EUR"); 
   $quote->collectTotals();
  }
}
```

The above event is not firing for me, Is there any other way to implement this functionality?

**Note:** The accepted answer working well but once the invoice is created, its changing to default currency again.

Can anyone advise me please why that event is not firing even after placing globally?.

Comment: Have you tried "sales_order_place_before" event of Magento?

Comment: @Sumit, No not tried it.I'll try that but the functionality will work?

Comment: Yes, it'll work with the Quote. You can try it and please confirm.

Comment: @Sumit, No That is also not working,

Comment: Hav you tried the following even checkout_submit_before

Comment: @DavaGordon, No. I'll try that now

Comment: @DavaGordon,No that event also not triggered!! did cache flush and checked it

Comment: have you tried checkout_controller_onepage_saveOrder

Comment: also if your using the events i give you then you should change $observer->getEvent()->getQuote() to $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()

Comment: one fine thing have you tried $quote->setCurrency('EUR'); when setting the currency

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98027/discussion-between-manjunath-and-dava-gordon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try with below code.

> events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_save_commit_after">
    <observer name="sumit_custom_order_currency" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\OrderSaveCommitAfter" />
</event>
</config>
```

> OrderSaveCommitAfter.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class OrderSaveCommitAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /* @var $order Order */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        if (!$order->getId()) {
            //order not saved in the database
            return;
        }
        $order->setBaseCurrencyCode('EUR');
        $order->setGlobalCurrencyCode('EUR');
        $order->setOrderCurrencyCode('EUR');
        $order->setStoreCurrencyCode('EUR');
        $order->save();
    }
}
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: hello, @Sumit can u update the code to set quote currency here

Comment: I've updated my code, please check.

Comment: thanks but unfortunately the event is not firing for me

Comment: Can you please share the scenario where you want to trigger this code.

Comment: When customer or guest places the order, also pls let me know when that event will trigger?

Comment: OK, please check https://mage2.pro/t/topic/3573 for sales order events in detail

Comment: hi @sumit , my requirement is to change the quote currency to EUR even if INR is set in admin, so which event i need to use here, pls help me with that.

Comment: Anything comes into the log file??

Comment: no, I can't see any logs, the event is not triggered..

Comment: So the order is created in the Admin with your custom currency?
"sales_order_save_commit_after". With this, you need to load order data instead of the quote in the observer file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98028/discussion-between-manjunath-and-sumit).

Comment: hello, @Sumit, the this code working well from the frontend, once invoice is created, all values will changes to default currency code.

Comment: can you please check once and update me your ideas..I need to avoid changing the base_currencycode and global_currency_code

Answer (score 2):

This is a work around use Plugin instead of Observer.

**Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
    <plugin name="Module_OrderAfterSave" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\OrderAfterSave" sortOrder="10" disabled="false" />
</type>
```

Then **Vendor\Module\Plugin\OrderAfterSave.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;

class OrderAfterSave
{
private $logger;
protected $objectManager;
protected $orderRepositoryInterface;
protected $_coreSession;

public function __construct(
    ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepositoryInterface,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $coreSession
) {
    $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->orderRepositoryInterface = $orderRepositoryInterface;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;
}

public function afterSave(\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepo, $order)
{
    $currencyCode = 'EUR';

    $order->setBaseCurrencyCode($currencyCode);
    $order->setGlobalCurrencyCode($currencyCode);
    $order->setOrderCurrencyCode($currencyCode);
    $order->setStoreCurrencyCode($currencyCode);
    $order->save();

    return $order;
}
```

**I hope this will help you!!**

Answer (score 0):

These answers are all a bit overly complicated.

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index">
        <observer name="switch_currency_gbp" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CurrencyCheck" />
    </event>
```

CurrencyCheck.php

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

class CurrencyCheck implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
   
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    )
    {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }
    

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $currencyCode = 'GBP';
        $quote = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();

        if($quote->getCurrency() != $currencyCode )  {
            <-- Object Manager For Example Only -->
            \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($currencyCode);

        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```